# Convert a python df which is in pivot format to a proper row column format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following dataframe

```
id a_1_1, a_1_2, a_1_3, a_1_4, b_1_1, b_1_2, b_1_3, c_1_1, c_1_2, c_1_3
1    10     20      30     40   90      80     70   Nan     Nan     Nan     
2    33     34      35     36   nan    nan    nan    11     12      13
```

and i want my result to be as follow

```
id  col_name 1    2    3
1    a       10   20   30
1    b       90   80   70
2    a       33   34   35
2    c       11   12   13
```

I am trying to use `pd.melt` function, but not yielding correct result ?

Comment: What happened to values of column `a_1_4` in your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can reshape using an intermediate `MultiIndex` after extracting the letter and last digit from the original column names:

```
(df.set_index('id')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                               d.columns.str.extract(r'^([^_]+).*(\d+)'),
                            names=['col_name', None]
                              ), axis=1))
   .stack('col_name')
   .dropna(axis=1)  # assuming you don't want columns with NaNs
   .reset_index()
)
```

Variant using [`janitor`'s](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io) [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

(df
 .pivot_longer(index='id', names_to=('col name', '.value'),
               names_pattern=r'([^_]+).*(\d+)')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.dropna(thresh=d.shape[1]-2))
 .dropna(axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   id col_name     1     2     3
0   1        a  10.0  20.0  30.0
1   1        b  90.0  80.0  70.0
2   2        a  33.0  34.0  35.0
3   2        c  11.0  12.0  13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
df = df1.melt(id_vars=["id"], 
        var_name="Col_name", 
        value_name="Value").dropna()


df['Num'] = df['Col_name'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
df['Col_name'] = df['Col_name'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

df = df.pivot(index=['id','Col_name'], columns='Num', values='Value').reset_index().dropna(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
Num id  Col_name    1   2       3
0   1   a          10.0 20.0    30.0
1   1   b          90.0 80.0    70.0
2   2   a          33.0 34.0    35.0
3   2   c          11.0 12.0    13.0
```

Comment: I am taking this approach, in the example that i have mentioned, index columns do not have duplicate values, where as in my case duplicate values exists due to which pivot is failing with the error 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'